# Terraform cidrsubnet function for Azure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm having a really tough time getting the cidrsubnet function to work with count.index for Azure. Below is my config and error I receive, do I need to add output commands calling out subnet names? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
variable "subnet-count" {
    description = "number of subnets"
    type = number
    default = 2
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {
  count                = var.subnet-count
  name                 = "${var.nameofvnet}-subnet${count.index}"
  resource_group_name  = var.nameofresourcegroup
  virtual_network_name = var.nameofvnet
  address_prefixes     = cidrsubnet(["10.88.0.0/16"], 8, count.index)
```

}

```
Error message below

Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 27, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnets":
│   27:   address_prefixes     = cidrsubnet(["10.88.0.0/16"], 8, count.index)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ while calling cidrsubnet(prefix, newbits, netnum)
│ 
│ Invalid value for "prefix" parameter: string required.


I tried many different syntax for the cidrcount command and non have been successful
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove brackets in prefix. With brackets it's list not string.

```
cidrsubnet("10.88.0.0/16", 8, count.index)
```